# display json to html table using laravel 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, laravel-4

ok im trying to display my json data to my html table. i tried so many solutions in the net but still end up nothing. im also new to this so called MVC framework, json, jquery. im using laravel though.

i get this JSON String from server as response

```
[{"CUSTNAME":"RUSTANS SUPERCENTER, INC. - CDO ","SOPNUMBE":"STDINV710342 ","REFRENCE":"fac00110658A ","DOCDATE":"2014-07-31 00:00:00.000","DOCAMNT":"2400.00000","sopcustname":"RUSTANS SUPERCENTER, INC. - CDO ","curtrxam":".00000","TXTFIELD":"08\/07\/14 \r08\/07\/14\r08\/20\/14"}]
```

here is my controller code (**"http://localhost:8080/mytestproject2/public/FilterData"**)

```
    public function dosearch() {
    $param = Input::get('SOPNUMBE', '000000');
    $query = "EXEC CFAsp_ColRls2 '$param'";

    $resultset = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query);
    return json_encode($resultset);
}
```

here is my js

```
$('#myidfirst').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        var mydata = $('#myidfirst').serialize();

        $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/mytestproject2/public/FilterData",
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: mydata,
          success: function(data) {
            if(data){
              var len = data.length;
              var txt = "";
              if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                  if(data[i].CUSTNAME && data[i].SOPNUMBE && data[i].REFRENCE && data[i].DOCDATE && data[i].DOCAMNT && data[i].sopcustname && data[i].curtrxam && data[i].TXTFIELD){
                    txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].CUSTNAME+"</td><td>"+data[i].SOPNUMBE+"</td><td>"+data[i].DOCDATE+"</td><td>"+data[i].DOCAMNT+"</td><td>"+data[i].sopcustname+"</td><td>"+data[i].curtrxam+"</td><td>"+data[i].TXTFIELD+"</td></tr>";
                  }
                }
                if(txt != ""){
                  $("#testing").append(txt);
                }
              }
            }
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

just need to know what am i missing in this one
regards everyone :D

Comment: Umm, you've put `localhost` link. That won't work for anyone else, except you, unless we exactly clone your server setup. Also, you say *but whenever i run it i always got this output*... What output? Since we're unable to debug this application, it would help to provide some results, i.e. what happens when this code runs, do you get any js errors, does anything appear in table etc.

Comment: well yeah only, me since im still developing this proj. heres the output im talking about [{"CUSTNAME":"RUSTANS SUPERCENTER, INC. - CDO ","SOPNUMBE":"STDINV710342 ","REFRENCE":"fac00110658A ","DOCDATE":"2014-07-31 00:00:00.000","DOCAMNT":"2400.00000","sopcustname":"RUSTANS SUPERCENTER, INC. - CDO ","curtrxam":".00000","TXTFIELD":"08\/07\/14 \r08\/07\/14\r08\/20\/14"}]

i didnt get any errors though, it will just output those data and thats not what i want it to be. it should display to my html table

Comment: Well you should edit your question and structure it correctly, move the output up so your text makes a bit more sense. Also, where is this coming from? You don't seem to have any `console.log` or `alert` inside your success function. I bet you have a js error showing up, because your function gets a parameter `response` and you're using undefined `data` inside if and for.

Comment: oh thanks im gonna do that. sorry the parameter should be "data" not "responce" i just change it. but the same output shows.

im still not so familiar about console.log cause i just shifted to web dev.

Comment: I don't know what other programming languages do you know to give you analogy, but console.log is a command to output text to webdev console. Try putting `console.log(data);` as a first line inside `success` function, open web developer console and see what's the output.

Comment: i think i found the console.log and it show this

 Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
http://localhost:8080/assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1421202131848 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I was right about the error. Read what it says and fix it. This is not even related to your original error. By the way, this is not said `console.log`, it's an error message from another library you're using, and it, as it says, failed to load. You'll have it right when you'll see something like server response you're mentioning. But the console.log doesn't even matter, you should fix the errors inside console first and then try if your application is working or not.

Comment: thanks ill try to crack those errors.

Comment: Can you provide the controller code that returns your JSON data, i.e `public/FilterData`?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. the public function dosearch() at the top is the code :D